# Excel SUM Statement with a WHERE parameter?

Tags: excel

I've got the below code which gets me the total value of F18 on all worksheets from "First" to "Last"

```
=SUM(First:Last!F18)
```

How can I amend this so it uses the below logic:

Total of F18 in all worksheets between First & Last WHERE B12 = "Name1"

Name1 can appear on several worksheets

Answer (score 1):

Not easy with a formula unless you have a list of all worksheets. If you have that list named as `WSList` then you can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&WSList&"'!B12"),"Name1",INDIRECT("'"&WSList&"'!F18")))
```